# What is the difference?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Can you tell me if there's a relevant difference between the codes below?

```
$stmtLA = "SELECT `title`, `audio`, `capa`, `link`, `alt` FROM table WHERE type = 'tes' AND formato = 'mv' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
$IDLA       = $conn->query($stmtLA);
```

And

```
$IDLA = $conn->query("SELECT `title`, `audio`, `capa`, `link`, `alt` FROM table WHERE type = 'tes' AND formato = 'nv' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");
```

I have many queries like this one, to get records from my db and print on the screen. I was thinking if i get performance if i use the 'single line' query.

Comment: You won't get a better performance if you save yourself a variable.

Comment: formato = 'nv' vs formato = 'mv' is a difference in the queries so they should return different results. Maybe there was an intention to make the value "mv" variable? This can be done by preparing the query in a variable with PDO

Comment: @SanderVisser Nop, this is just random values. Just to ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version creates a throw-away variable that's then used in the query. The second version just runs the query.

There's no difference in terms of performance, but in the first there is a *risk* here that you may misfire and execute the wrong query.

I strongly recommend following the second style because you've loaded the query directly and it's visually obvious what's executing. In the former it's possible to have two slightly similar variables with two completely different queries in use, like `$sql3` and `$sql8` which at a quick glance might seem identical.

Comment: Alright, but i would get any security against attacks, if i put the SELECT into a variable, like the first version?

Comment: In both cases this is 100% dependent on the query being safe. The only difference is the direct operation versus indirect operation. To secure your query be absolutely certain you're using *prepared statements with placeholder values*. The query you show here has no dynamic data, so there's no way to comment on security issues. If you introduce user data into your actual query you may have huge problems. `query(...)` cannot deal with user data. `prepare()` can.

Comment: As i said, i use this query to get records from my db and print on the screem (with a foreach loop), it's not even on the user-side. So do you think that i should use prepared statements with placeholder values?

Comment: You can see a full example of my code here: https://pastebin.com/ShvbLQKu

Comment: Since the query itself has no dynamic components there's no difference.

Comment: I think i got what you meant with `the query itself has no dynamic components`. But didn't understand completely what you said. You meant that since my query itself has no dynamic components, then i don't need to use prepared statements with placeholder values?

Comment: That's right. It's when you introduce arbitrary data, like `$name`, that things can get really ugly if you're not careful. Instead use placeholders like `?` or `:name` to represent that and bind the data when you execute.